# Change global value of product attribute in observer

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute, ce-1.9.0.1, store-view

I have an observer for `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`. From here I change `delivery_time`:

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
$productId = $stockItem->getData('product_id');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->setData('delivery_time', $rot)->getResource()
  ->saveAttribute($product, 'delivery_time');
```

This works fine if I work in the backend. But if I order this product `delivery_time` is changed for the current store view not global.

How can I change the attribute's global value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Version 1

Faster, without `load`:

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
$productId = $stockItem->getData('product_id');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
   array($productId), //product ids
   array('delivery_time' => $rot), //what to update
   Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID //store id to update
);
```

## Version 2

With load

Replace this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

with this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load($productId);
```

Comment: I only had a solution with `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` and thought there must be a better way. This is perfect!